# UK Consumer Rights - Final Right to Reject Time Limit

Tags: united-kingdom, consumer-protection, human-rights

I was sold the wrong product online, however the seller refuses to refund me since their refund policy is 14 days, and it has been 40 days since delivery of the product.

On websites [such as Which?](http://www.which.co.uk/consumer-rights/advice/how-to-reject-a-faulty-product-and-get-your-money-back) (section 3, *Contact the retailer*), it is stated that there is a right to reject the product even after 30 days. However, I have been unable to find an explicit declaration of the time limit for this "final right to reject" in the [Consumer Rights Act on legislation.gov.uk](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/contents), and the seller is refusing to refund me if I cannot find one.

So the question is: where exactly is the time limit (if any) for the final right to reject stated in the Consumer Rights Act?

Answer (score 1):

Direct their attention to the following sections:

> 11 Goods to be as described
>
> 19 Consumer's rights to enforce terms about goods
>
> 22 Time limit for short-term right to reject

The short term limit is 30 days but this stops running for any period where you are awaiting a replacement.

> 24 Right to price reduction or final right to reject

Applies after the product has been replaced at least once and is still unsatisfactory.